Confused about how event loop fetch tasks from task queue
Recently I saw the event loop session shared by Jake Archibald. As he mentioned in the time 27:55 of the video, it seems the event loop get task from queue one item per round

However, we I read the document on mozilla In depth: Microtasks and the JavaScript runtime environment, it says this:

When executing tasks from the task queue, the runtime executes each task that is in the queue at the moment a new iteration of the event loop begins.

It seems all  the items in the queue will be fetched when the round began
So which one is correct? 1 item per round or all existing items per round?

at the moment a new iteration of the event loop begins = one task at a time - not all of them at once

It says “each task” not ‘all tasks’ so I’d still interpret that to mean one task at a time.

It's "one item per round", using the specs wordings:


If the event loop
has a task
queue
with at least one
runnable
task,
then:


Let taskQueue be one such task queue,
chosen in an
implementation-defined
manner.


[note]  Remember that the microtask queue
is not a task
queue,
so it will not be chosen in this step. However, a task
queue
to which the microtask task
source
is associated might be chosen in this step. In that case, the
task
chosen in the next step was originally a
microtask,
but it got moved as part of spinning the event
loop.


Set taskStartTime to the unsafe shared current time.

Set oldestTask to the first runnable
task
in taskQueue, and remove
it from taskQueue.

If oldestTask's document
is not null, then record task start
time
given taskStartTime and oldestTask's
document.

Set the event loop's
currently running
task
to oldestTask.

Perform oldestTask's steps.



So the only task that is ran in one event-loop's "round", is "the first runnable task in taskQueue".
The MDN article should be updated since indeed that wording is confusing. (Arguably, it's not the only confusing part of that article, since tasks do not necessarily execute JS, and microtasks are not in direct opposition of tasks, since they'll also be executed between some callbacks).
